# Products stuck in quick cart

Tags: magento2.3, ajax, shopping-cart

When I add multiple items to a cart, they get stuck in the quick cart. They even pass from computer to computer some how and I am unable to remove them. This is one of the pages affected
https://woodstove-fireplaceglass.com/shop/products.html
To recreate the issue, add an item to the cart from the catalog page. The result is 4 items are now in the quick cart but only one item will be shown on the shopping cart page. This issue appears on Chrome and Edge but not Firefox.
Magento 2.3.5-p1

update: the add to cart behavior sometimes works, but an additional issue is that the quantity update in the quick cart will add a different item if the amount is updated.

Comment: i can't replicate your problem but i am facing issue in minicart while updating product quantity

Comment: I just disabled a plugin Yireo_Webp2 and that seemed to fix the add to cart issue, but yes, now the mini cart is adding a different item once the product quantity is increased

Comment: well then the issue is because of third part modules i think so that needs to be debug

Comment: for minicart check minicart file it works with KO check its overridden files you will find some lead there

Comment: I've disabled several modules and updated others. The issue still persists. Somehow when a customer adds a product to their cart, another customer will have the same item added to their cart.

Comment: How would a product get stuck in the cart transferring from customer to customer. Could it be a server issue?

Comment: well i think magento is not creating separate quote or session for separate customer thats why it merge both customers cart this could be by some custom customization

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with js when you load the website for the first time and scroll down you get this issue.

because of this js issue, your cart is not working properly.

```
ajaxinfinitescroll.js:90 Uncaught TypeError: $.mage.formKey is not a function
    at c.<anonymous> (ajaxinfinitescroll.js:90)
    at c.proxy (jquery.js:535)
    at IASCallbacks.fire (jquery-ias.min.js:17)
    at IASCallbacks.fireWith (jquery-ias.min.js:41)
    at c.fire (jquery-ias.min.js:115)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ias.min.js:95)
    at HTMLLIElement.opt.complete (jquery.js:7906)
    at fire (jquery.js:3238)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3368)
    at tick (jquery.js:7761)
```

Issue occur because of this $.mage.formKey();

I will recommend that put that trigger or what ever make ajax call on scroll in $(document).ready(function () {});

And Last are you sure $.mage.formKey(); exits in js